# Defining categories for all integers

Tags: r

Suppose I want to group the positive integers as follows:

```
 int     cat
 1-3     0
 3-5     1
 5-7     2
  .      .
  .      .
```

In R, how would you do this? A function like this:

```
function1 <- function(n) {
   if n >= 1 && n <= 3 then cat = 0
   etc.
 }
```

seems to be inefficient because you have to manually define the categories.

Comment: `?findInterval`, `?cut`

Comment: Did you mean to have your integers fall into multiple categories?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
int <- 1:10
cat <- cut(int, seq(1, max(x)+1, 2), right=F)
cat_numeric <- as.numeric(cat) - 1
```

Alternatively if you want to arrive directly at the category number for an individual arbitrary number, a function like this might work better:

```
y<- function(x) (x+1)%/%2-1
```

Comment: This assumes that I specify the integers in advance. What if I wanted to categorize 454545454?

Comment: I think I've addressed that now

Comment: Not sure that your integer division is working quite as intended. Alternatively, `floor(x/3 - 0.1)`.

Comment: @jbaums The question includes boundary integers mapping to two categories, the OP indicated that that was unintentional so the correct mapping is ambiguous

Comment: The OP's `if n >= 1 && n <= 3 then cat = 0` suggests `3` should be mapped to `0`, but the table of mappings contradicts, and so yes it's unclear and @Trevor should clarify in the question. :)